# Is Linux password login inherently insecure or is it just that people use weak passwords?

Tags: passwords, linux

The normal advice you see everywhere when setting up a Linux server is to setup SSH and disable the password login. Is this because there is some security issue with password logins or because sooner or later someone will use a weak password? If a complex generated password was to be used would it be secure?